# How to handle common code in multiple HTML's using javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an application which has almost 30 html's and they share some common code to which i f i made any changes i need to change it on every page. Below is the piece of code which i am using on all pages.

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li class="current"><a href=".html" ></a></li>
    <li><a href=".html"></a></li>
    <li><a href=".html"></a></li>
    <li><a href=".html"></a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
```

Is there any solution to which i can keep it on a single file and reuse it where ever i want?

Comment: Considered using PHP `include`?

Comment: it can be done easily by server-side script. What's your server-side script?

Comment: he's requesting it done by javascript/jquery... so what's with all the php answers?

Comment: I don't have any idea about php i want it using jquery/javascript can you people plese help using that?

Comment: @GonçaloVieira I guess that all the PHP answers are related to the fact that it is the best/most obvious solution. Even if he is requesting js/jquery he may not be aware of PHP inclusion, and might actually benefit from something he didn't know before. With that said: android phonegap, my answer contains two solutions using purely javascript/jquery, tell me if you find something difficult.

Comment: @Sunyatasattva calling it the best is a matter of personal opinion, what I meant was, this question had nothing to do with PHP, it's for an app, so if it's run offline, I don't see how the server-side part of it would be helpful... PS: I did upvote your answer because you actually spoke of more than just one way of loading it ( even if mostly on a web-focused approach )

Answer (score 17):

There are several ways you can achieve this inclusion to keep your code more maintainable.

### PHP

---

Of course the first that comes to mind is if you want to use PHP is the usage of [`include()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) which includes and evaluates the code in your external file or script.

You can use it as such:

```
<?php include('path/to/file.html'); ?>
```

**Note!** Be careful: your container file must be a `.php` file in order for this directive to be evaluated from the server. You don't need to do anything but changing the file extension, for that to happen. And, of course, make sure that your server can parse PHP.

Also, beware of the difference with [`include_once()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php), which I would not recommend in this case.

### SSI (Server side include)

---

If you don't want to use PHP, you can do that very simple and clean with a [**Server side include**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/howto/ssi.html)<sup>[[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes)]</sup>. An SSI looks like an HTML comment:

```
<!--#include virtual="your.html" -->
```

**Note!** You will have to make sure to have [`mod_include`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_include.html) installed and enabled in your Apache server, and to add the following directive either in your `httpd.conf` or `.htaccess` file:

```
Options +Includes
```

Read the doc link above for more information.

### Client-side includes

---

Your question actually specifies to do this in JS or jQuery. Not sure if it does because you were not aware of the server-side options, or if you really wanted a client-side one. In any case, there are also some client-side solutions.

Given the possibility, **I would recommend the server-side** solutions to your problem.

#### IFrame element

---

The [`<iframe>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/iframe) element includes content from an external file in a separate area in your page. You can use it like so:

```
<iframe src="your.html" width="x" height="y"><p>Fallback text</p></iframe>
```

#### Object element

---

The [`<object>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/object) element does a similar thing to the `<iframe>`, but while the latter is designed more as a means to *sandbox* an application, the former feels more integrated in your page. The usage is as follows:

```
<object type="text/html" data="your.html"></object>
```

#### Javascript insertion

---

Convert the code into a Javascript file and instruct the file to insert the content into the DOM. Here is an example

**external.js**

```
var element = '<div>
                   <ul>
                     <li class="current"><a href=".html" ></a></li>
                     <li><a href=".html"></a></li>
                     <li><a href=".html"></a></li>
                     <li><a href=".html"></a></li>
                   </ul>
               </div>';
```

**container.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="external.js"></script>
<script>
     document.getElementById('#containing-element').innerHTML(element);
</script>
```

#### AJAX

---

jQuery can help you deal with some AJAX calls easily. You could use [`jQuery.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) or [`jQuery.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/). I would suggest you use the latter, as `load()` injects the loaded element directly into the DOM, and also as you can specify exactly which part to load, which is nifty especially if you would like to store all your includes in one external HTML file.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($){
    $('#containing-element').load('your.html');
});
```

Comment: jQuery.load() here would be one of the propper ways of loading it on the app.

Answer (score 0):

Old thread, but came across this requirement myself. My requirement was to do it in the client side with plain javascript. One off case, that is, only one html (appHeader.html) as common code.

In each of the required pages, defined a containing div with id="head-container" and in the body/window onload event, included

```
    await fetch("./appHeader.html")
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then((html) => {
        document.getElementById("head-container").insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", html);
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

If you use php you can have that code in one single file and use `include 'filename.php';`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Comment: Can you use a templating system like `moustache.js`?

Answer (score -1):

You already got answer for `PHP`, but if you don't want or can't use it you can save it in JS file:
`test.js`

```
document.write('<div>\n\
  <ul>\n\
    <li class="current"><a href=".html" ></a></li>\n\
    <li><a href=".html"></a></li>\n\
    <li><a href=".html"></a></li>\n\
    <li><a href=".html"></a></li>\n\
  </ul>\n\
 </div>');
```

and include it:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
```

But of course better with `PHP`.

Comment: If you would like google to index you page, don't rely on a js-solution

Comment: Indeed, but OP speak about application, so in this case it probably will change nothing.

Comment: considering it is an app, this code will most definitelly not be served...
but then again most people don't read the question...