# Put a universal resizable header over a large number of HTML pages

Tags: html, html-table

I am working with an old website designed in the mid-90s, which is coded very primitively: left-hand menu done via tables, no CSS, etc.  The site consists of a bunch of .html pages.  Instead of re-coding the site, I want to leave everything in place but put a header over every page with a banner saying "Go to the new site" or something similar.

This way the banner would look modern, but everything else can retain the retro look (including, most importantly, the URL structure).  The header should be 100 pixels tall and fill the whole horizontal space regardless of how the tables below it are coded.  The plan is to bulk-copy and paste the new code in every individual page.

What's the best way to write this header?

Comment: This answer I gave a while ago might help you with your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15832282/how-to-handle-common-code-in-multiple-htmls-using-javascript-or-jquery/15833078#15833078

Comment: Why won't a simple div at the beginning work?

Comment: Add your `div` to each page, just after the opening `body` tag. Add your CSS link to the header.